# Limit of $\frac{2^n+2.71^n+\frac{4^n}{n^4}}{\frac{4^n}{n^4}+n^33^n}$ - what is wrong with my proof?

Tags: limits, proof-verification

Here's quite a hairy sequence, the limit of which I need to find as $n\rightarrow\infty$:

$$\frac{2^n+2.71^n+\frac{4^n}{n^4}}{\frac{4^n}{n^4}+n^33^n}$$

The Squeeze Theorem seemed like a good idea so here's what I've done:

$\frac{2^n+2^n+2^n}{2^n+2^n}<=\frac{2^nn^4+2.71^nn^4+4^n}{4^n+n^73^n}=\frac{2^n+2.71^n+\frac{4^n}{n^4}}{\frac{4^n}{n^4}+n^33^n}<=\frac{n^n+n^n+n^n}{n^n+n^n}$

The left and right sequences have the $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}=\frac{3}{2}$. So theoretically the sequence for which $\lim$ is being searched should also converge to $\frac{3}{2}$. But WolframAlpha tells me that the correct answer is $1$. So where is an error in my logic?

One more question, in my "proof" I couldn't show that for sufficiently large $n$: $n^33^n<=n^n$ and this is important in order for my transformation to be considered as correct. Is there any way to show it without derivatives?

Comment: For all $n,4^n\gt 3^n\gt 2^n\dots$.  In this case, that means that the $4^n$ portion is dominant over all the other terms.  You might consider multiplying the expression by $\dfrac {4^{-n}}{4^{-n}}$ to see how it works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your inequalities is you have bounded both the numerator *and denominator* below and then both above. I.e., It's not the case that $a/b < c/d$ if $0 < a < c$ and $0 < b < d$.

*Hint:* Multiple top and bottom by $n^4.4^{-n}$. You have a $1$ in both places and all other terms can be shown to tend to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the hint :) Could you tell me what's wrong with my 'proof' though?

Answer (score 3):

The problem in your approach is this.
$a,b,c,d>0$, if $a>b$ and $c>d$ you cannot conclude $\frac{a}{c}>\frac{b}{d}$

Comment: You're right. I don't know why I didn't see that earlier...

Answer (score 1):

The inequalites are wrong. To make a fraction larger you have to make the numerator larger  and the denominator smaller. To make the fraction smaller make the numerator smaller and the denominator larger.

To compute the limit, observe that the dominating term in the numerator and denominator is $4^n/n^4$. The other terms are neglegible.

Answer (score 1):

rewriting your term in the form
$\frac{\frac{n^4}{2^n}+\frac{2.71^n\cdot n^4}{2^{2n}}+1}{1+\frac{n^7\cdot 3^n}{2^{2n}}}$
you will see that the limit is $1$